# AvalonEdit XSHD Syntax Highlighting - Ending a Span

Tags: .net, regex, wpf, razor, avalonedit

I'm using AvalonEdit and working on adding syntax highlighting for a file (with syntax a bit like razor). It's my first time using XSHD files so please forgive me if this is actually easy.

The issue I'm experiencing can be seen with the following example code:

```
Not C#

@{
    public void DoStuff() {
        // C# highlighting here
    }

    public void DoMoreStuff() {
        // C# highlighting here
    }
}
```

Within the `@{` and `}` I need to apply C# syntax highlighting. So I am doing this in xshd: (simplified)

```
<Span ruleSet="RazorCode" multiline="true">
    <Begin color="CodeBlockStartEndTags">\@\{</Begin>
    <End color="CodeBlockStartEndTags">\}</End>
</Span>
<RuleSet name="RazorCode">
    <Import ruleSet="C#/" />
</RuleSet>
```

And this is what I am observing:

[image]

Clearly what's happening is the `<End color="CodeBlockStartEndTags">\}</End>` tag is ending the span as soon as it finds the very next closing brace `}`. When actually it should skip this brace because there is an open brace before it.

So I need it to count open braces and pair them up with the close braces, to actually end the span on the correct closing brace.

Is this possible in XSHD?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML syntax highlighting keeps track of the stack of RuleSet activations. You can count braces by activating the RuleSet recursively:

```xml
<Span ruleSet="RazorCode" multiline="true">
    <Begin color="CodeBlockStartEndTags">\@\{</Begin>
    <End color="CodeBlockStartEndTags">\}</End>
</Span>
<RuleSet name="RazorCode">
    <Import ruleSet="C#/" />
    <Span ruleSet="RazorCode" multiline="true">
        <Begin>\{</Begin>
        <End>\}</End>
    </Span>
</RuleSet>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly and was exactly what I needed. I spent almost 2 days trying to figure this out and got nowhere. The world needs more people like you :)